# How to disable autofill in browser if autocomplete is not working?

Tags: javascript

I tried several solutions on the internet and none of them are working for me.
The saved passwords which most of the browsers store , that should not autofill in the login form.
Need solution in javascript or jquery.

Comment: can you show some sample code of what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide us with some more information about your problem and what exactly you have tried so far? E.g. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don’t see any problem here that would require a solution to begin with. What is actually needed here, is respecting the user’s choices. Whether I use a password manager in my browser or not, should not be your concern to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete still works on an `<input>`despite having `autocomplete="off"`, but you can change off to a random string, like `nope`.
example:

```
<input type="text" name="field" autocomplete="nope">
```

Comment: [not a cross browser solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the mozilla offical info how to do that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

It' s a good source of information about how some things should be done.  In my app i got something like this, and it works:

```
 <form class="login-form" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Login" autocomplete="someTextHere"> 
</form>
```